# Relational database management system, not for server but client-side

Tags: relational-database

I am making a relational database for a friend who is not tech savvy.  I am looking for something that she can upload the correctly formatted excel files into and be able to see the relationships clearly.

> (<1>[John Smith]<2>[Sam Jones] rather than <1><6><2><244>, etc.)

I know I can make my own web-based system but I was not sure if there was an open source (or freely available) system already available, either desktop-based or web-based.  I tried googling it but I am afraid that I am using the wrong keywords.  (I only got server-side systems)

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's ugly and expensive, but MS/Access does this well.  It's good for beginners and Excel integrates very well.  If she has Office Professional she already has it. It also supports ODBC so it can use other database engines.

Comment: Thanks! I forgot about that one :)

Comment: Look for database design software, such packages often can generate "entity relationship diagrams".  You might also look for that. I think Visio can generate those: http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/visio-help/create-a-database-model-also-known-as-entity-relationship-diagram-HA010115477.aspx

Answer (score 1):

As far as desktop DBMS goes, as Peter Wooster pointed out (+1) MS Access is the most user friendly for people who are used to Office (e.g. especially Excel).

If you are thinking of building something with a web GUI (i.e. with ASP.NET) then you can get SQL Server Express for free and it can be deployed on a client PC.

There are other typically server-based RDBMS systems with workstation-friendly editions, such as MySQL and even Oracle (although there is nothing friendly about Oracle, workstation or otherwise).

Comment: Ok, thank you.  I have been looking for awhile now and I still cannot find anything better than Access (which seems hard to believe).  Thanks for your help